# Deserialize a generic object that contains a generic object

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I have a problem that I did not find how to solve it.
I have this class which "data" is a generic bject

```
class ApiResponse <DataType>
 (
      @SerializedName("requestType")
      val type : RequestTypeEnum,

      @SerializedName("requestState")
      val state : RequestStateEnum,

      @SerializedName("requestAI")
      val data : DataType?

 ) : BaseVO()
```

and I have a class that fetch data from the webservice or from the database, or both.. When instantiating this class, I pass the type of result that I have to return. The result returned from the database, does not have the same type as the result returned from the webservice. When the result must be obtained from the database, by instantiating this class, I pass a simple generic type that can be for example "User", but when the result must be obtained from the webservice, I must instantiate this class with a generic type "ApiResponse" which also contains a generic type object.

This is my class :

```
abstract class DataSourceManager<ParamsType , ResultType>
```

and here's how I instantiated it

```
return object : DataSourceManager<List<String> , ApiResponse<List<String>>>()
{...}.asLiveData
```

when I display in the log the result as String, it displays correctly

```
{
  "requestType": "WEB_SOCKET_TEST_SPONSOR_CODE",
  "requestState": "ERROR",
  "requestAI": [
    "ERROR_MISSING_INFORMATIONS"
  ]
}
```

But the problem is when I try to deserialize it to the type of result passed by instantiating the class, it can not be converted to the desired type.

here is my deserialization try

```
val apiResponse = convertFromString<ResultType>(pApiResponseAsString)
.
.
.

 fun <T> convertFromString(pDataAsString : String?) : T?
 {
      val dataType : Type = object : TypeToken<T>(){}.type
      return Gson().fromJson<T>(pDataAsString , dataType)
 }
```

when I try to treat the result as a converted object, I get an error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.reflect.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to com.PackageName.ApiResponse
```

But when I display the result in the log, it finds this format invalid :

```
{requestType=WEB_SOCKET_TEST_SPONSOR_CODE, requestState=ERROR, requestAI=[ERROR_MISSING_INFORMATIONS]}
```

Some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: type erasure.

When you do `fun <T> convertFromString(data: String) : T` and try to get data type: `val dataType : Type = object : TypeToken<T>(){}.type` your type would be `Object`

Luckily for us, Kotlin has [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html).

Change your function declaration to:

`inline fun <reified T> convertFromString(data: String?) : T?`, and everything shall work.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank your for your answer. I have already tried this method, but it asks to use a class as reified type parameter instead 'ResultType' which is generic.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. What's `ResultType` and how is it different from any other class?

Comment: i have 2 generic type when i instanciate this class :
abstract class DataSourceManager<ParamsType , ResultType>.. ResultType is  generic that can be a data from the local database, or a response from the webservice.

Comment: Still don't see any problem with that. You deserialize `ResultType`, not `DataSourceManager`. Try posting the code that calls `convertFromString()`, maybe that will give out some clue.

Comment: I too did not understand what the problem is! everything I wrote seems logical and correct! I wrote my code in another answer, you can see it now, thank you :)

Comment: even if the webservice response is String, i tried to deserialize it to String .. deserialization is done successfully without any problem, then i deserialize it to my generic type and display it in the log, and all is fine, i got my object that i am waiting for.. but when i want to pass it to the operationCompleted() abstract method or posting it to my livedata, i get this error : java.lang.String cannot be cast to my generic type.. he can not understand that my ResultType is really a ApiResponse <List <RequestStateEnum >>.. i will lose my brain...

Comment: As I already wrote, your type gets erased somewhere along the way. Make your generics `reified` one by one if you want to find where it happens.

Comment: i guess it will be the best solution to not waste even more time .. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

the method that instantiates the DataSourceManager class, I have two generic types, "List < String>" is the parameter type of the webservice query, and ApiResponse< List < RequestStateEnum >> is the response type of the webservice.

```
fun verifyReferralCode(pReferralCode : String) : LiveData<ApiResponse<List<RequestStateEnum>>>
     {
          return object : DataSourceManager<List<String> , ApiResponse<List<RequestStateEnum>>>()
          {
               override fun createWebserviceCall() : ApiRequest<List<String>>
               {
                    return ApiRequest(RequestTypeEnum.VERIFY_REFERRAL_CODE , listOf(pReferralCode))
               }

               override fun sessionToken() : String?
               {
                    return null
               }

               override fun operationCompleted(params : List<String>? , result : ApiResponse<List<RequestStateEnum>>)
               {}

          }.asLiveData
     }
```

This is ApiResponse object

```
class ApiResponse<DataType>
 (
      @SerializedName("requestType")
      val type : RequestTypeEnum,

      @SerializedName("requestState")
      val state : RequestStateEnum,

      @SerializedName("requestAI")
      val data : DataType

 ) : BaseVO()
```

This is DataSourceManager class, it is not complete but it contains the necessary code that I need now.

```
abstract class DataSourceManager<ParamsType , ResultType>
{
 @MainThread
 abstract fun createWebserviceCall() : ApiRequest<ParamsType>

 @MainThread
 abstract fun sessionToken() : String?

 @WorkerThread
 abstract fun operationCompleted(params : ParamsType? , result : ResultType)


 private val resultLD = MediatorLiveData<ResultType>()
 val asLiveData : LiveData<ResultType> get() = resultLD


 init
 {
      performWebRequest()
 }


 private fun performWebRequest()
 {
      val request = createWebserviceCall()

      val webserviceSource = WebSocketWS.executeRequest(request.requestType , request.toString())

      resultLD.addSource(webserviceSource) {pApiResponseString ->

           resultLD.removeSource(webserviceSource)

           //pApiResponseString is String which contains a valid Json object.
           val apiResponse = convertFromString<ResultType>(pApiResponseString )

           //resultLD.postValue(apiResponse)
           //saveResultToCache(request.requestAI, apiResponse!!)
      }
 }


 private fun <T> convertFromString(pDataAsString: String?) : T?
 {
      val dataType = object : TypeToken<T>(){}.type

      return Gson().fromJson(pDataAsString, dataType)
 }


 @MainThread
 private fun saveResultToCache(params : ParamsType? , result : ResultType)
 {
      Execution.instance.databaseIO.execute {

           operationCompleted(params, result)
      }
 }
}
```